# Split string in a stream Java

Tags: java, string, java-stream

I have a POJO class Product

```
List<Product> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Product(1, "HP Laptop Speakers", 25000));
list.add(new Product(30, "Acer Keyboard", 300));
list.add(new Product(2, "Dell Mouse", 150));
```

Now I want to split the list to get output as `HP-Laptop-Speakers&&Acer-Keyboard&&Dell-Mouse.`

I just want a single liner in stream.
So far I have managed to get

```
Optional<String> temp = list.stream().
                   map(x -> x.name).
                   map(x -> x.split(" ")[0]).
                   reduce((str1, str2) -> str1 + "&&" + str2);
System.out.println(temp.get());
```

Output: `HP&&Acer&&Dell`

Can someone help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to **join**, not **split**. Join = take several parts and construct a single string. Split = take a single string and extract several parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the `split()` operation is not necessary. While you could split all the pieces and then join them together like that, it is far simpler to use a `replace` or `replaceAll` call instead.

Secondly, the reduce operation will not be very efficient since it is creating lots of intermediary `String`s and `StringBuilder`s. Instead, you should use the `String` joining Collector, which is more efficient:

```
 String temp = list.stream()
              .map(x -> x.name.replace(" ", "-"))
              .collect(Collectors.joining("&&"));
```

Answer (score 2):

The second `map` operation you write keep the first word.

Instead, here what you can do :

1. Replace the spaces (`\\s` as regex) by a `-`

   ```
   Optional<String> temp = list.stream()
                               .map(x -> x.name)
                               .map(x -> x.replaceAll("\\s", "-"))
                               .reduce((str1, str2) -> str1 + "&&" + str2);
   ```
2. Split on space, and then join with the `-`

   ```
   Optional<String> temp  = list.stream()
                                .map(x -> x.name)
                                .map(x -> String.join("-", x.split("\\s")))
                                .reduce((str1, str2) -> str1 + "&&" + str2);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use collector on stream of strings:

```
.collect(Collectors.joining("&&"))
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this would be to override the toString() method in the Product class to print the name as you want it formatted and then iterate through the list concatenating each result onto a longer string.

Answer (score 0):

```
Optional<String> temp = list.stream().map(x -> x.name)
                  .map(x -> x.replaceAll("\\s", "-"))
                  .reduce((str1, str2) -> str1 + "&&" + str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace this portion `map(x -> x.split(" "))` with `map(x -> x.replaceAll("\\s","-"))`